Color not coming in Make4ht
My codes are:
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,makecell}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgf} % 
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}

\definecolor{highNeuro}{HTML}{F8F7F5}
\definecolor{lowNeuro}{HTML}{7B3A98} 
\newcommand*{\opacity}{100}% 
\newcommand*{\minvalNeuro}{-1.0}% 
\newcommand*{\maxvalNeuro}{0.5}% 

\newcommand{\gradientNeuro}[1]{
    % The values are calculated linearly between \minvalNeuro and \maxvalNeuro
    \ifdimcomp{#1pt}{>}{\maxvalNeuro pt}{#1}{
        \ifdimcomp{#1pt}{<}{\minvalNeuro pt}{#1}{
            \pgfmathparse{int(round(100*(#1/(\maxvalNeuro-\minvalNeuro))-(\minvalNeuro*(100/(\maxvalNeuro-\minvalNeuro)))))}
            \xdef\tempa{\pgfmathresult}
            \cellcolor{highNeuro!\tempa!lowNeuro!\opacity} #1
    }}
}

\definecolor{highICC}{HTML}{7B3A98}
\definecolor{lowICC}{HTML}{F8F7F5} 

\newcommand*{\minvalICC}{-0.5}% 
\newcommand*{\maxvalICC}{1.0}% 

\newcommand{\gradientICC}[1]{
    % The values are calculated linearly between \minvalICC and \maxvalICC
    \ifdimcomp{#1pt}{>}{\maxvalICC pt}{#1}{
        \ifdimcomp{#1pt}{<}{\minvalICC pt}{#1}{
            \pgfmathparse{int(round(100*(#1/(\maxvalICC-\minvalICC))-(\minvalICC*(100/(\maxvalICC-\minvalICC)))))}
            \xdef\tempa{\pgfmathresult}
            \cellcolor{highICC!\tempa!lowICC!\opacity} #1
    }}
}

\definecolor{highWMH}{HTML}{F8F7F5} 
\definecolor{lowWMH}{HTML}{7B3A98}  

\newcommand*{\minvalWMH}{-1.0}% 
\newcommand*{\maxvalWMH}{0.5}% 

\newcommand{\gradientWMH}[1]{
    % The values are calculated linearly between \minvalWMH and \maxvalWMH
    \ifdimcomp{#1pt}{>}{\maxvalWMH pt}{#1}{
        \ifdimcomp{#1pt}{<}{\minvalWMH pt}{#1}{
            \pgfmathparse{int(round(100*(#1/(\maxvalWMH-\minvalWMH))-(\minvalWMH*(100/(\maxvalWMH-\minvalWMH)))))}
            \xdef\tempa{\pgfmathresult}
            \cellcolor{highWMH!\tempa!lowWMH!\opacity} #1
    }}
}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
\textbf{ROI\textbackslash Network} &
  \textbf{VoxResNet} &
  \textbf{VNet} &
  \textbf{3D Unet} &
  \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Attention\\ UNet\end{tabular}} &
  \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}AnatomyNet\\ (SE)\end{tabular}} &
  \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}AnatomyNet\\ (CE+SE)\end{tabular}} &
  \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}AnatomyNet\\ (Vanilla)\end{tabular}} &
  \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}AnatomyNet\\ (CE)\end{tabular}} &
  \textbf{nnU-Net} &
  \textbf{nnU-Net-CRUISE} \\ \hline
  \textbf{Visual}                                  & \gradientICC{0.40}          & \gradientICC{0.27}          & \gradientICC{0.39}        & \gradientICC{0.40}          & \gradientICC{0.32}          & \gradientICC{0.41}          & \gradientICC{0.34}          & \gradientICC{0.53}          & \gradientICC{0.54}        & \gradientICC{0.55}   \\ \hline
  \textbf{Motor}                                   & \gradientICC{0.59}          & \gradientICC{0.03}          & \gradientICC{0.25}        & \gradientICC{0.03}          & \gradientICC{0.11}          & \gradientICC{0.04}          & \gradientICC{0.08}          & \gradientICC{0.46}          & \gradientICC{0.72}     & \gradientICC{0.75}      \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}

It produced the output as:

I need to convert into HTML format, for this I'm using Make4ht, the table converted nicely but without color. I need the color also in the HTML file, please advise

make a smaller example. Only one colored cell is needed to demonstrate such a problem.

@UlrikeFischer Sorry for the full code, now modified per you suggested and thanks

This is caused by the use of colors not recognized by TeX4ht's support for the xcolor package. This version of xcolor.4ht should fix it:
% xcolor.4ht (2024-05-09-15:10), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 2007-2009 Eitan M. Gurari
% Copyright 2009-2024 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2024-05-09-15:10}

\input color.4ht
\def\rowc@l@rs[#1]#2#3#4%
 {\global\rownum=\z@
  \global\@rowcolorstrue
  \@ifxempty{#3}%
    {\def\@oddrowcolor{\@norowcolor}}%
    {\def\@oddrowcolor{\a:rowcolors{#3}%
                       \gdef\CT@row@color{\CT@color{#3}}}}%
  \@ifxempty{#4}%
    {\def\@evenrowcolor{\@norowcolor}}%
    {\def\@evenrowcolor{\a:rowcolors{#4}%
                        \gdef\CT@row@color{\CT@color{#4}}}}%
  \if@rowcmd
    \def\@rowcolors
     {#1\if@rowcolors
        \o:noalign:{\relax\ifnum\rownum<#2\@norowcolor\else
                 \ifodd\rownum\@oddrowcolor\else\@evenrowcolor\fi\fi}%
      \fi}%
  \else
    \def\@rowcolors
     {\if@rowcolors
        \ifnum\rownum<#2\o:noalign:{\@norowcolor}\else
        #1\o:noalign:{\ifodd\rownum\@oddrowcolor\else\@evenrowcolor\fi}\fi
      \fi}%
  \fi
  \CT@everycr{\@rowc@lors\the\everycr}%
  \ignorespaces}
\NewConfigure{rowcolors}{1}
\def\@rowc@lors{\o:noalign:{\global\advance\rownum\@ne}\@rowcolors}
\def\showrowcolors{\o:noalign:{\global\@rowcolorstrue}\@rowcolors}
\def\hiderowcolors{\o:noalign:{\global\@rowcolorsfalse\@norowcolor}}
\def\:temp#1#2#3{{\set@color}}
\HLet\color@block\:temp
\def\:temp#1#2#3{}
\HLet\boxframe\:temp
\def\strip:fin:excl#1!{#1}
\expandafter\def\csname get!HColor\endcsname#1!#2//{%
  \def\current:color:name{#1\if!#2!\else!\strip:fin:excl#2\fi}%
  \if\relax#2\relax
  %\expandafter\ifx \csname HColor!#1\endcsname\relax
     \let\HColor=\relax
     \expandafter\ifx \csname\string\color @#1\endcsname \relax\else
   \expandafter\ifx \csname colortyp:\endcsname\relax \else
   \extractcolorspec{#1\if!#2!\else!\strip:fin:excl#2\fi}\tmp:color%
   \expandafter\convertcolorspec\tmp:color{HTML}\tmp:color%
   \def\HColor{\#\tmp:color}%
   \Configure{HColor}{\current:color:name}{\HColor}%
      \csname colortyp:\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endcsname
         \csname\string\color @#1\expandafter\endcsname
         \space .!//%
\fi \fi
%
  \else%
     \ifcsname HColor!#1\endcsname%
       \csname HColor!#1\endcsname #2//%
     \else
       \get:xcolorcss{#1!#2}{\HColor}%
       \Configure{HColor}{\current:color:name}{\HColor}%
     \fi%
  \fi
}
\expandafter\def\csname c:HColor!gray:\endcsname{%
     \expandafter\def\csname HColor!gray\endcsname##1!##2//}
\Configure{HColor!gray}{\Configure{HColor}{}{}}
\expandafter\def\csname c:HColor!rgb:\endcsname{%
     \expandafter\def\csname HColor!rgb\endcsname##1,##2,##3!##4//}
\Configure{HColor!rgb}{\Configure{HColor}{}{}}
\expandafter\def\csname c:HColor!cmyk:\endcsname{%
     \expandafter\def\csname HColor!cmyk\endcsname##1,##2,##3,##4!##5//}
\Configure{HColor!cmyk}{\Configure{HColor}{}{}}
\def\get:xcolorcss#1#2{%
   \expandafter\extractcolorspec\expandafter{#1}{\tsf:color}%
   \expandafter\convertcolorspec\tsf:color{HTML}\tsf:color%
   \edef#2{\#\tsf:color}%
}

\:CheckOption{color}\if:Option
\pend:defI\@declaredcolor{%
  \ifdefined\end:def:color\end:def:color\else\aftergroup\b:textcolor\fi
  \a:textcolor\def\end:def:color{\b:textcolor}%
}
\fi

\Hinput{xcolor}
\endinput


The result looks correctly:


As usual, Great answer...Thanks a lot...
