make4ht: Obtaining adaptive dark and light mode in HTML version
I like to obtain a conversion from the following TEX file to HTML with a proper adaptive feature for viewing in dark and light modes.
Here is the configuration file mycfg.cfg that I am using:
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/722062/114006

\Preamble{xhtml,fancylogo}

% handle bullet in myitems
\ConfigureEnv{myitems}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="myitems">}}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\IgnorePar\HCode{</div>}}{}{}
% set padding as you like
\Css{.myitems ul.itemize1{list-style:none;display:block;padding-left:1em;}}
\Css{.myitems ul.itemize1 li{display:block;margin:0;padding:0.1em;}}
\Css{.itemizeHead{float: left; margin-left: -1em; width: 1em;}}
\Css{li.itemize{list-style: none;}}

% heading boxes
\renewcommand{\resheading}[1]{%
\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="resheading">}%
\fcolorbox{shadecolorB}{shadecolorB}{#1}%
\HCode{</div>}%
}

\catcode`\:=11
% convert shadecolor to CSS
\get:xcolorcss{shadecolor}{\:shadecolor}
\Css{.resheading .colorbox{display:block; width:100\%;padding:3pt;font-size: 1.2em; font-weight:bold; box-sizing:border-box;}}
\Css{.resheading{border: 3px solid \:shadecolor;box-sizing:border-box;padding:1px;background:black;}}

\ConfigureList{itemize}%
   {\EndP\HCode{<ul \a:LRdir
          class="\getClass{itemize}itemize\expandafter\the
          \csname @itemdepth\endcsname">}%
       \afterGetClass{itemize}%
       \PushMacro\end:itm
\global\let\end:itm=\empty}
   {\PopMacro\end:itm \global\let\end:itm \end:itm
\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi
    \EndP\HCode{</li></ul>}\ShowPar}
   {\end:itm \global\def\end:itm{\EndP\Tg</li>}\HCode{<li class="\getClass{li}itemize"><span class="itemizeHead" aria-hidden="true">}\afterGetClass{li}}
   {\HCode{</span>}\par\ShowPar}

\catcode`\:=12

% handle \school
\renewcommand{\school}[4]{%
\begin{tabular}{l r}%
  \textbf{#1} & #2\\ \textit{#3} & \textit{#4} \\%
\end{tabular}%
}

% document styling
\Css{body{margin: 1em auto; max-width: 85ch}}

% table styling
\Css{table{width:100\%;}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble

The main.tex file:
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\newlength{\outerbordwidth}
\pagestyle{empty}
\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=blue,      
    urlcolor=blue,
    pdftitle={CV},
}
\urlstyle{same}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\setlength{\outerbordwidth}{3pt}  
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.75} 
\definecolor{shadecolorB}{gray}{0.93} 
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.25in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.25in}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.5in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{7in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.3in}
\setlength{\topskip}{0in}
\setlength{\voffset}{0.1in}
% \setlength{\parindent}{0cm}  
%-----------------------------------------------------------
% Custom commands
\newcommand{\resheading}[1]{
  \parbox{\textwidth}{\setlength{\FrameSep}{\outerbordwidth}
    \begin{shaded}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\framebox[\textwidth][l]{\setlength{\fboxsep}{4pt}\fcolorbox{shadecolorB}{shadecolorB}{\textbf{\sffamily{\mbox{~}\makebox[6.762in][l]{\large #1} \vphantom{p\^{E}}}}}}
    \end{shaded}
  }\vspace{-11pt}
}

\newcommand{\school}[4]{\vspace{1.5mm}
  \textbf{#1} \hfill #2 \\ \textit{#3} \hfill \textit{#4} %\vspace{1.5mm}
}

\newenvironment{myitems}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]}{\end{itemize}}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular*}{7in}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
    \textbf{\Large Name} & \textbf{Date} \\ Address & \textit{\href{mailto:gmail.com}{gmail.com}}
\end{tabular*}

\resheading{Education}
\begin{myitems}
    \item[]
        \school
        {University Name}
        {Location}
        {Master of Science - Physics}
        {Year}
        \begin{myitems}
            \item[] Thesis Title
            \item[] Supervisor Name
        \end{myitems}
\end{myitems}

\end{document}

I am putting the generated main.html in a webpage through <iframe> in the index.html:
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <style>
      html, body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden; /* Prevent scrolling on the main page */
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        background-color: #121212;
        color: #e0e0e0;
      }
      .navbar {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #333;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        height: 50px; /* Fixed height for the navbar */
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 1000;
        padding: 0 10px;
      }
      .navbar a, .toggle-btn {
        display: block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 20px;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      .navbar a:hover, .toggle-btn:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
        color: black;
      }
      .content {
        margin-top: 50px; /* Margin to account for the navbar */
        height: calc(100% - 50px); /* Height to fill the remaining space */
      }
      .content div {
        height: 100%; /* Ensure the divs inside .content take up full height */
        overflow: hidden; /* Prevent scrolling inside the divs */
      }
      iframe {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border: none;
        overflow: auto; /* Allow scrolling inside the iframe only */
      }
      .light-mode {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        color: #000000;
      }
      .light-mode .navbar {
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
      }
      .light-mode .navbar a, .light-mode .toggle-btn, .light-mode {
        color: black;
      }
      .light-mode .navbar a:hover, .light-mode .toggle-btn:hover, .light-mode {
        background-color: #ddd;
        color: black;
      }
    </style>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>CV</title>
    <script>
      function toggleMode() {
        document.body.classList.toggle('light-mode');
        const isLightMode = document.body.classList.contains('light-mode');
        applyModeToIframes(isLightMode ? 'light' : 'dark');
      }

      function applyModeToIframes(mode) {
        const iframes = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');

        iframes.forEach(iframe => {
          const iframeDoc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
          iframeDoc.body.style.backgroundColor = mode === 'dark' ? '#121212' : '#ffffff';
          iframeDoc.body.style.color = mode === 'dark' ? '#e0e0e0' : '#000000';

          const links = iframeDoc.querySelectorAll('a');
          links.forEach(link => {
            link.style.color = mode === 'dark' ? '#bb86fc' : '#0000ee'; // Adjust link colors
          });
        });
      }

      function applyDefaultMode() {
        // Apply dark mode by default
        document.body.classList.remove('light-mode');
        applyModeToIframes('dark');
      }

      window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        const iframes = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');

        // Apply default dark mode once the iframe content is fully loaded
        iframes.forEach(iframe => {
          iframe.addEventListener('load', applyDefaultMode);
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="navbar">
      <div>
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="toggle-btn" onclick="toggleMode()">Toggle Dark/Light Mode</a>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
      <div>
        <iframe
          src="main.html"
          frameBorder="0"
          scrolling="auto"
        ></iframe>
      </div>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>

The background colors of headings (i.e.  \resheading{Education}) in main.html stay the same (light) in the dark mode as it was in the light mode. The following screenshots are taken from Google Chrome (Version 127.0.6533.88) in Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS. Also, it appears the same from Firefox (Version 128.0.3). I also checked that this appearance is not affected by the dark/light mode of these 2 browsers or the OS.
Dark Mode (Default view)

Light Mode (Using the Toggle button)

I like to configure it so that all the text and background colors adapt accordingly in dark and light modes.

For getting color in HTML, please refer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/716339/color-not-coming-in-make4ht

You need to provide a CSS definition for elements that have explicitly set background color, such as colorboxes. The easiest way is to use make4ht filters to post-process the CSS file. This way you can extract unique IDs of color boxes, invert the background color using Lua and then add CSS code that will tell browser to use the inverted color in the dark mode. It can look like this:
local filter = require "make4ht-filter"

local function invert(hex)
  local gethex = function(start) return tonumber(hex:sub(start, start+1), 16) end
  local r,g, b = gethex(1), gethex(3), gethex(5)
  local nr, ng, nb = 255 - r, 255 - g, 255 - b
  return string.format("%02X%02X%02X", nr, ng, nb)
end

local process = filter {
  function(content)
    local boxes = {}
    -- find all background color definitions for colorboxes
    for id, color in content:gmatch("(%#colorbox%d+){background%-color:%s*%#([A-F0-9]+);}") do
      -- save inverted color
      table.insert(boxes, {id = id, color = invert(color)})
    end
    local newcontent = {}
    -- make media queries for boxes
    for _, box in ipairs(boxes) do
      newcontent[#newcontent+1] = string.format(".dark-mode %s{background-color: #%s; }", box.id, box.color)
    end
    return content ..  table.concat(newcontent, "\n")
  end
}

Make:match("css", process)

Compile using:
$ make4ht -e build.lua -c config.cfg main.tex

You will also need to change your index.html to correctly set the color mode class in the HTML document included using iframe:
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <style>
      html, body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden; /* Prevent scrolling on the main page */
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        background-color: #121212;
        color: #e0e0e0;
      }
      .navbar {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #333;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        height: 50px; /* Fixed height for the navbar */
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 1000;
        padding: 0 10px;
      }
      .navbar a, .toggle-btn {
        display: block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 20px;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      .navbar a:hover, .toggle-btn:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
        color: black;
      }
      .content {
        margin-top: 50px; /* Margin to account for the navbar */
        height: calc(100% - 50px); /* Height to fill the remaining space */
      }
      .content div {
        height: 100%; /* Ensure the divs inside .content take up full height */
        overflow: hidden; /* Prevent scrolling inside the divs */
      }
      iframe {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border: none;
        overflow: auto; /* Allow scrolling inside the iframe only */
      }
      .light-mode {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        color: #000000;
      }
      .light-mode .navbar {
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
      }
      .light-mode .navbar a, .light-mode .toggle-btn, .light-mode {
        color: black;
      }
      .light-mode .navbar a:hover, .light-mode .toggle-btn:hover, .light-mode {
        background-color: #ddd;
        color: black;
      }
    </style>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>CV</title>
    <script>
      function toggleMode() {
        document.body.classList.toggle('light-mode');
        const isLightMode = document.body.classList.contains('light-mode');
        applyModeToIframes(isLightMode ? 'light' : 'dark');
      }

      function applyModeToIframes(mode) {
        const iframes = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');

        iframes.forEach(iframe => {
          const iframeDoc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
          iframeDoc.body.style.backgroundColor = mode === 'dark' ? '#121212' : '#ffffff';
          iframeDoc.body.style.color = mode === 'dark' ? '#e0e0e0' : '#000000';

          iframeDoc.body.classList.remove('light-mode');
          iframeDoc.body.classList.remove('dark-mode');
          if(mode == 'light'){
            iframeDoc.body.classList.add('light-mode');
          } else {
            iframeDoc.body.classList.add('dark-mode');
          }

          const links = iframeDoc.querySelectorAll('a');
          links.forEach(link => {
            link.style.color = mode === 'dark' ? '#bb86fc' : '#0000ee'; // Adjust link colors
          });
        });
      }

      function applyDefaultMode() {
        // Apply dark mode by default
        document.body.classList.remove('light-mode');
        applyModeToIframes('dark');
      }

      window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        const iframes = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');

        // Apply default dark mode once the iframe content is fully loaded
        iframes.forEach(iframe => {
          iframe.addEventListener('load', applyDefaultMode);
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="navbar">
      <div>
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="toggle-btn" onclick="toggleMode()">Toggle Dark/Light Mode</a>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
      <div>
        <iframe
          src="main.html"
          frameBorder="0"
          scrolling="auto"
        ></iframe>
      </div>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>

This is the result in dark mode:


I have updated my question to give more detailed context.

@raf yes, it looks as expected in Firefox

@raf the JavaScript code doesn't work for me in both Firefox and Chromium. The toggle changes just the color of the header. The page in iframe remains in the light mode.

Kindly check now, I have updated the code and the details. I am not getting any effect from using the build.lua on my updated setup.

@raf the updated code should work

Thank you. Now, in the dark mode, are the background colors inside and outside the heading box Education the same? If so, can they be made a bit different, as there's a difference in the light mode colors? In your screenshot, they are different, but I am getting the same black background on my browser.

@raf the problem is that you use the same background color in the dark mode as is the inverted color from the box. Try to use darker gray in the light mode and the inverted color should be different.

I see. I am unsure if I am wrong, but it seems like the color inversion is different on the navigation bar of the toggle button. It appears close to the same gray as the shaded box in the light mode, but it looks different in the dark mode. Am I getting it wrong?

@raf I don't know. These colors are declared by your index.html file.
